# C# at first button click my program doesn't fill all array elements, why?

Tags: c#

I've created a "random password generator" app (I'm a beginner, just for practicing) and somehow at first button click it only fills 5-6-7 elements of my array.

This code might be strange (for generating random characters), I just looked ASCII table and searched for numbers, letters and I've put them into random min and max number.

```
 string[] ch = new string [11];
 Random r = new Random();

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt64(r.Next()) % 3 == 0)
            ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(49, 57)));
         else if (Convert.ToInt64(r.Next()) % 3 == 1)
             ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(65, 89)));
         else if (Convert.ToInt64(r.Next()) % 3 == 2)
             ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(97, 122)));
     }
     pass.Text = (Convert.ToString(ch[0] + "" + ch[1] + "" + ch[2] + "" + ch[3] + "" + ch[4] + "" + ch[5] + "" + ch[6] + "" + ch[7] + "" + ch[8] + "" + ch[9]));
```

To decide to use number (ascii 49-57) small letters (65-89) or bigs (97-122) I just made a random number then (truncating divided?) divided by 3 and result is then 0,1 or 2 then made ifs for them.

Might be stupid but its my own idea. So when I click on the button, at first time it shows only about 5,6,7 elements of arrays. Anybody knows why?

Comment: Why are you using the integer values? Just use the ASCII characters themselves: `r.Next((int)'a', (int)'z')`

Comment: Also, your program only creates passwords that are exactly 9 characters? You could easily expand this program to create passwords of any length. No need to do that ridiculous last line, just pass the `char[]` to the `String()` constructor: `pass.Text = new String(ch)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not only the first time that the code fails to put values in all positions.

You have this control structure:

```
if (Convert.ToInt64(r.Next()) % 3 == 0)
  ...
else if (Convert.ToInt64(r.Next()) % 3 == 1)
  ...
else if (Convert.ToInt64(r.Next()) % 3 == 2)
  ...
```

As you are picking a new random number for each condition, there is a 29.63% chance that neither of them will be true.

If you watch the result closely, you will see that most of the time there are some characters that don't change.

You should pick one random number and check its value:

```
switch (r.Next(3)) {
 case 0:
   ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(49, 57)));
   break;
 case 1:
   ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(65, 89)));
   break;
 case 2:
   ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(97, 122)));
   break;
}
```

A different approach would be to put all the characters that you want to use in a string, and pick from that:

```
string chars = "123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

ch[i] = chars.Substring(r.Next(chars.Length), 1);
```

This is especially useful if you want to exclude some characters that are easy to mix up, like 0, O, o, 1 and l, then you just exclude them from the string:

```
string chars = "23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz";
```

Comment: Thanks this is more expert way but less to write. Thanks now I learnt some.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Convert.ToInt64(r.Next()) % 3 == 0)
    ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(49, 57)));
else if (Convert.ToInt64(r.Next()) % 3 == 1)
    ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(65, 89)));
else if (Convert.ToInt64(r.Next()) % 3 == 2)
    ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(97, 122)));
```

When you call Next three times, you get three different numbers. Because of this, you can fail all three if statements.

Do this instead

```
int i = r.Next(3);
if (i == 1)
    ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(49, 57)));
else if (i == 2)
    ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(65, 89)));
else
    ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(97, 122)));
```

Comment: at division by 3, the result is always 0,1 or 2. So I dont understand it sorry. Could you explain it?

Comment: Each time you call Next(), there is a new number generated. Therefore you are generated 3 different values and use modulo on them. You better call Next() once, save that value and use it for your if statements.

Comment: Yes, but when you are picking a different number each time, you can get three numbers in a row that fails each if test

random gives 4, mod 3 gives 1, fails == 0//
random gives 3, mod 3 gives 0, fails == 1//
random gives 6, mod 3 gives 0, fails == 2//

You have to use the same random value each time to ensure you hit one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the results in a variable before your if statements. The results change each time you do r.Next().

```
int result = Convert.ToInt64(r.Next());

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        if (result % 3 == 0)
            ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(49, 57)));
         else if (result % 3 == 1)
             ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(65, 89)));
         else if (result % 3 == 2)
             ch[i] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(r.Next(97, 122)));
     }
     pass.Text = (Convert.ToString(ch[0] + "" + ch[1] + "" + ch[2] + "" + ch[3] + "" + ch[4] + "" + ch[5] + "" + ch[6] + "" + ch[7] + "" + ch[8] + "" + ch[9]));
}
```

etc...